# Accessing pods directly VS ClusterIP service to access all exposed ports

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-service

I would like to expose one pod that has a lot of ports (including big port range, thousands of them) to the cluster members (namely as a **ClusterIP** service). So manually listing them in the service definition is not really possible (Kubernetes does not support exposing port ranges yet).

The container in the pod will run Samba AD DC (here I am just showing that there are really a lot of ports): https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_AD_DC_Port_Usage

I have been trying to find out how to expose the whole pod (like DMZ on a service); if it is possible at all. I am not sure if this is the best approach to get the goal I want (exposing the whole pod to the internal cluster network).

To summarize the question, is there any way to expose the whole ports (or the whole pod let's say) to the internal cluster network (or to any network of choice) using *Service*?

I am not sure if I am missing something that can be done better in this regard.